# How to start a group chat in Google Talk client?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk

I created a group chat with Google Talk gadget, but I can't do it in the desktop client.
Maybe pidgin can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "group chats" are a nonstandard feature, incompatible with XMPP multi-user chats, and can only be created using the Talk gadget in Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own chat room address by [generating a uuid](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1460575).

Comment: That tip works for Empathy. But what about the official client?

Answer (score 1):

http://hamisageek.blogspot.com/2009/04/google-talk-group-chat-on-pidgin.html here's a link on how you can do it:

> When someone invites you to join a group chat, you get a message with
>   some text that looks like private-chat-xxxxxxx@groupchat.google.com
>   and a link that launches your browser that leads you to a page that
>   launches gtalk gadget. Note that "xxxxx" represents some random string
>   that is most likely used to identify the group chat room.
>
> So here's how to join a Gtalk group chat from Pidgin using the above
>   information :
>
> 1. Click Buddies from the menu
> 2. Then click Join Chat
> 3. In the account drop down, make sure you use a Gtalk account.
> 4. For the Room textfield, paste private-chat-xxxxxxx
> 5. For the Server te