# show real names in Pidgin Google Talk group chats

Tags: pidgin, google-talk, xmpp

I'm able to join group chats [following these instructions](http://hamisageek.blogspot.com/2009/04/google-talk-group-chat-on-pidgin.html), but all the usernames except mine are just long hex strings. Anyone know a way to display real [nick]names?

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/211576/27137) it seems unlikely.

If I right-click on one of those hex strings and pick `Info`, it shows the person's Google Profile, so it does seem like Pidgin *could* display real names.

Comment: It doesn't look like anyone can, according to this: https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/14664